# How to set all except one element in a vector of bools to true?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a `vector` in C++.

```
vector<bool> trumpIsGoodFor(42);
```

I need to set all the elements except the 24th element to `true`.

I want to do it using a one/two line or *elegant* assignment using C++11/14.

Comment: You mean _except_?

Comment: @c650 Yes, all the elements leaving the 24th element.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for this. Seems easy enough:

```
std::vector<bool> vec(42, true);
vec[23] = false; /* didn't know if you meant 24th in 0-index or 1-index */
```

Comment: It is guaranteed

Comment: Is that a question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the constructor

```
vector<bool> trumpIsGoodFor(42,true);
trumpIsGoodFor.at(23) = false; //use you can also use [23] subscript
```

You can see the documentation for the [Vector Constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) here.

`std::vector` contains a `.at()` function which checks whether your index is in the range of the vector, [documentation here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/).